# I want 'a' element which has php would be applied addClass 'on'

Tags: php, jquery

I am a super beginner of PHP, so I am still struggling to get the hang of it.

I want this situation: if each `a` has been clicked, background-color fills in so that the user can know what has been clicked. For this, I usually used jQuery, and it worked every time.

However, it has not worked since I put `"index.php?lang=en"` in href, but when I changed `"index.php?lang=en"` into "#", it works but the languages don't change.

Please check my code and let me know what the problem is.

index.php

```
<?php 
  include "config.php";
?>

  <header> 
   <div class="header-con">          
      <nav class="lang">
        <a href="index.php?lang=en" class="lang_a">en</a>
        <a href="index.php?lang=ko" class="lang_a">ko</a>
      </nav>      
    </div>    
   </header>
```

jQuery

```
  (function($){
    $(function(){    
      var $header = $('header'),
          $lang_a = $header.find('.lang a');    

          $lang_a.on('click', function(){        
               $lang_a.removeClass();
               $(this).addClass('on');
        });       
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
.lang a {
   padding: 0 6px;    
   font-weight: normal;
   transition: all .3s
 }
 .lang a:hover,
 .lang a.on {
   background-color: #191970;
   color: #eee
 }
```

config.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    else if ($_GET['lang'] == "ko")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "ko";
}

require_once "languages/".$_SESSION['lang'].".php"; 
?>
```

And here are the languages files.

en.php

```
<?php 

    $lang = array(

        "sin" => "A",
        "sin_title" => "B",
        "sin_con" => "C"

    );

?>
```

ko.php

```
<?php 

    $lang = array(

        "sin" => "가",
        "sin_title" => "나",
        "sin_con" => "다"

    );

?>
```

Comment: you haven't posted any of your language files, how can we tell why they cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update the class name of the link (an 'a' element) right?

you can do it by get the current session and do something like these :D

```
<?php include "config.php"; ?>
<header>
  <div class="header-con">
    <nav class="lang">
      <a href="index.php?lang=en" class="lang_a <?php echo $_SESSION['lang']==='en' ? 'on' : ''; ?>">en</a>
      <a href="index.php?lang=ko" class="lang_a <?php echo $_SESSION['lang']==='ko' ? 'on' : ''; ?>">ko</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to do, and it works!! Honestly, I don't know why this code does look this way, so I will look it up! Thanks a million  :-D